# Same primers and different melting peaks for two samples (~1°C appart)

Tags: pcr, reverse-transcription

In the figure, you can see that melting peaks differ by ~1°C at each sample.

Should I be worried?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would have said that 1⁰C is not a significant difference but the technical replicates are so perfectly matching!! Are these samples from same source (tissue/cells etc)?

Comment: they are the same tissue (oviduct) from two different animals